# How could i detect Accident's in video clips by image processing

Tags: java, image-processing, opencv3.0

I am now working on image processing using Opencv.In my Vehicle accident detection module i was finding centroids of the vehicles.

I compared current Frame centroids with each other and then found euclidean distance between each of them.

The condition using which i tried to found accident frames is

```
If(distance < threshold)
```

Sysout("accident occurs");

I am unable to detect it correctly .How can i detect Vehicle accidents in video clips ?

P.s : I am using Top View Traffic dataset.

Comment: I doubt there is a simple way to detect vehicle collisions (distance<threshold is too simple).  A couple of years ago, I worked on a system that used on-board X/Y/Z accelerometers, which did some really complicated MatLab calculations, and even then couldn't always get it right.

Comment: what is the way than to properly find the accident's in  video clips, i am unsure of it . comprehensive answer needed for understanding.  @Neil

Comment: I would think it's a machine learning kind of thing.  You need 100s of videos of different kind of crashes (and non-crashes), to teach a neural network what is and isn't a crash.   There is no simple answer.

Comment: Thanks but i wont we using neural network  and to teach a neural network isnt it computationally expensive ?

Answer (score 2):

As @neil said there is no simple answer. But I would like to tell you how I would approach this non-trivial task.

- Get as much data as possible. This is critical to get this task done. If you have small amount of data, higher the chance you would choose parameters that work on the data you have but it won't work well when used on new videos. So this is key.
- I would start by looking at these videos to get a feel of what is happening. By feel, I mean, observe what features would be good to faithfully draw bounding boxes around the vehicles. Since you need to detect collision, bounding box dimension accuracy is critical. Because slightly larget bounding box could be detected as collision when there is none.
- You are using centroid, I think this won't work because it does not matter where the vehicle centre is and vehicle boundaries matter more. And since vehicle size varies, constant threshold wont work for sure(assuming you use constant threshold). You need to use centroids to find the nearest vehicles around a vehicle and then find the distances between the bounding box. If any distance is negative can be detected as collision(accident).
- Yes, coming back to bounding box. It is important to preprocess the images(possibly gaussian blur, but its trial and error).
- After preprocessing, use adaptive thresholding methods(try the ones that opencv provides) and experiment with it. Use color information in the video(not just gray). Exploit the road color(if it is constant). If you could remove road from the picture, all you will be left with is vehicles. This makes your job easier. But it can be done only if road color has no artifacts, but doable.

Hope this helps and good luck :)

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. @h4rshkin could you somehow explain me suppose 2 blobs whose distance is round about touch and go . when they gets close than the threshold they get merged and also got one centroid.
How could i find that those were two blobs ?

Comment: Sure, Will try and answer in the morning. Sleeping now

Comment: But tell me clearly what you mean 2 blobs whose distance is round?

Comment: Blobs means Binary large object .. I binarized my frames so after some morphological operations i get some white and black pixels .. mostly after operations the white portions are the vehicles portion ..

Comment: I meant distance is round. What does that mean. Anyway, are you using just images or video? If only images it will be slightly difficult to find that those were two blobs. But if it is a video you can track the blobs and find collision.

Comment: I am working on videos which are divided into frames  and than further processing

Comment: Since you are using videos, you need to track the centroid frame to frame. If the bounding box collide, then there is a collision. Of course it is not as easy as I said it.